# Use lan to interface synergy while having wifi connected to internet

Tags: networking

[Similar question and solution](http://synergy-foss.org/osqa/questions/165/force-synergy-to-use-lan-rather-than-wireless)

I have lan and wifi connection, with internet connected to internet. I need to get synergy communicate computer to computer through lan without a switch, just passing through with an ethernet cable, without compromising the internet. I've tried the solution above but couldn't seem to work.

Even setting the lan to static and under the same subnet doesn't seem to work. Anyone with similar situation and got to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you use a static IP on all machines, or that the dynamic IP doesn't change.

If you have access and control over your /etc/hosts file(s), you can define a special name for the devices which have multiple interfaces, and use those names in the /etc/synergy.conf file to name the computers / screens.

e.g. in /etc/hosts :

192.168.1.10  laptop-wired

I'd recommend to have synergy connect through the wired network only. Make sure there's no firewall in between, or at least open the synergy port 24800. Having all machines on the same network helps.

hope this helps.